# `flash.discard` in Rails 2.3 fails because flash is a Hash, not a FlashHash

Tags: ruby-on-rails, hash, actionpack, rails-flash

Given a functional test such as:

```ruby
def test_exciting_rails_upgrades
    login(m=users(:manager))

    post :import_users_map_fields, :csv_file => fixture_file_upload('/users.csv', 'text/csv')
    assert flash.empty?
    flash.discard
    # other goodies omitted

end
```

In Rails 2.3.2 there are no errors, however in 2.3.15 the error is:

```
    NoMethodError: undefined method `discard' for {}:Hash
    /test/functional/broken_upgrades.rb:119:in `test_exciting_rails_upgrades'
```

Why is `flash` a `Hash` class instead of a `FlashHash`?

From the source it looks like both 2.3.2 and 2.3.15 ActionPack files  `lib/action_controller/flash.rb` create the `FlashHash` class and inherit from `Hash`.  However what is shown in this functional test in both 2.3.2 and 2.3.15 is a `Hash` class, not a `HashFlash`, so one cannot call discard on it.

Can anyone else reproduce this error with 2.3.15 and `flash.discard`?

Comment: It may be the way ActionController::TestRequest#flash is defined that is causing this problem in tests, but this code is the same in both 2.3.2 and 2.3.15:
    def flash
      session['flash'] || {}
    end

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are two test cases you can use to prove ActionController changes the type of 'flash' depending on whether or not it is already set.

In my app, you cannot see :index unless you're logged in, so in test_flash_is_now_a_flashhash you see that flash was set by the backend properly, while in test_flash_is_a_plain_hash it was not.

```ruby
def test_flash_is_a_plain_hash
  login(users(:permitted_user))
  get :index
  assert flash.instance_of?(Hash)
end

def test_flash_is_now_a_flashhash
  get :index
  assert_redirected_to :controller => "login"
  assert flash.instance_of?(ActionController::Flash::FlashHash)
end
```

You can see this for yourself in the ActionController::TestRequest code:

```ruby
def flash
    session['flash'] || {}
end
```

Update: This has been [fixed](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/2-3-stable/actionpack/lib/action_controller/flash.rb#L184) in Rails branch [2-3-stable](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/2-3-stable/).